# What is the point of representing a conic in homogeneous form?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, conic-sections, projective-geometry, quadratic-forms

In this textbook I am studying, they state the following:

> The equation of a conic in inhomogeneous coordinates is
> $$ax^2+bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0$$
> ie. a polynomial of degree 2. "Homogenizing" this by the replacements $x:x_1/x_3,y:x_2/x_3,$ gives:
> $$ax_1^2 + bx_1x_2+cx_2^2+dx_1x_3+ex_2x_3+fx_3^2=0$$
> or in matrix form
> $$\textbf{x}^TC\textbf{x}=0$$
> where the conic coefficient matrix C is given by
> $$\begin{bmatrix}
> a & b/2 & d/2\\
> b/2 & c & e/2\\
> d/2 & e/2 & f
> \end{bmatrix}$$

Is the point in homogenizing this so that we can represent a conic in quadratic form? What is the benefit of such a representation? I am new to homogeneous coordinates so it is a bit confusing to me behind the motivation of it for this particular use case.

Comment: From the view of projective geometry, there are no case distinctions.

Comment: It's the equation of the projective version of the conic, so you also include the "points at infinity".